# Recursive function to extract all files from a "filetree"

Tags: javascript

Trying to extract all files from a folder and all it's subdirectories. The content of a directory is called against an external api.

```
export const extractFiles = (filesOrDirectories) => {
  const files = [];
  const getFiles = (filesOrDirectories) => {
    filesOrDirectories.forEach(async fileOrDirectory => {
      if (fileOrDirectory.type === 'directory') {
        const content = await getDirectoryContent(fileOrDirectory.id);
        getFiles(content);
      } else {
        files.push(fileOrFolder)
      }
    });
  }
  // files should be returned here when it's done. But how do I know when there are no more directories 
};
```

A recursive function which calls itself when it founds a directory. Otherwise push the file to an array.

But how can I know when there are no more directories to extract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will know there are no more directories to explore when the function ends.

However it should be noted that since there is asynchronous code inside your `extractFiles` function, you will have to await the result of any following recursion.

```js
export const extractFiles = async(filesOrDirectories) => {
  const files = [];
  const getFiles = async(filesOrDirectories) => {
    for (const file of filesOrDirectories) {
      if (fileOrDirectory.type === 'directory') {
        const content = await getDirectoryContent(fileOrDirectory.id);
        await getFiles(content);
      } else {
        files.push(fileOrFolder)
      }
    }
  }

  await getFiles(filesOrDirectories)
  return files;
};

const extractedFiles = await extractFiles();
```

EDIT:

Please note, a `forEach` will function in [unexpected ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop) when combined with asynchronous code, please refactor to use a `for...of` loop.